# Powershell Forms - How to add context menu event handler to prevent open unless item selected?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a form with a listview for which I have a right click context menu. I'd like the menu to only appear if the right clikc is above the selected item in the listview - at the moment it appears anywhere in the listview windows and even if nothing is selected.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Foo"
$form.Size = '400,400'

$CMitemEnable = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$CMitemEnable.Text = 'Enable'
$CMitemDisable = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$CMitemDisable.Text = 'Disable'
$lvcontextmenu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip
$lvcontextmenu.ShowImageMargin = $false
$lvcontextmenu.Items.AddRange(@($CMitemEnable,$CMitemDisable))

$listviewbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$listviewbox.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$listviewbox.Location = '15,20'
$listviewbox.Size = '340,150'
$listviewbox.Columns.Add('Host',180) | Out-Null
$listviewbox.FullRowSelect = $true
$listviewbox.MultiSelect = $false
# $listviewbox.ContextMenuStrip = $lvcontextmenu

$InfoText = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InfoText.Location = '15,180'
$InfoText.Size = '340,120'
$InfoText.Multiline = $true
$InfoText.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$InfoText.ReadOnly = $true

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($listviewbox,$InfoText))

$listviewbox.Items.AddRange(@('Foobar1','foobar2'))


$listviewbox.Add_MouseDown({
    $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $null
    If($listviewbox.SelectedItems.Count){
        $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $lvcontextmenu
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`n" + ($this.SelectedItems[0].Text))
    }
    Else {
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`nNothing selected")
        $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $null
    }
})

# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

I've not done context menus before and can't see for the life of me how to implement the event handler for this - there's examples for C etc but can someone point me in the right direction for Powershell please?

Comment: Updated - this seems closer, but still not wokring as intended, the first right click in blank space after an item is selected still brings up the context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the following points:

- Don't set `ContextMenuStrip` for the `ListView`
- Handle `MouseClick` event, so first the item will be selected, then your code run. (As an alternative, if you prefer mouse down, then you need to need to put your logic in `BeginInvoke` to make sure it will run after selection of item.)
- Using `GetBound` method of the selected item and `e.Location`, check if the clicked location is inside the item rectangle
- Show the `ContextMenuStrip` using `Show` by passing `Cursor.Position`

Here is a working example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text ="Test"
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
    ($listView1 = [System.Windows.Forms.ListView] @{
        Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill;
        FullRowSelect = $true;
        View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details;
    })
))
$contextMenuStrip1 = [System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip]@{}
$listView1.Columns.Add("C1") | Out-Null
$listView1.Columns.Add("C2") | Out-Null
$listView1.Items.Add("Item1") | Out-Null
$listView1.Items.Add("Item2") | Out-Null
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Menu 1") | Out-Null
$contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Menu 2") | Out-Null

$listView1.Add_MouseClick({param($sender,$e)
    if ($e.Button -eq [System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons]::Right){
        if ($listView1.FocusedItem.GetBounds(
            [System.Windows.Forms.ItemBoundsPortion]::Entire).Contains($e.Location)){
            $contextMenuStrip1.Show([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position)
        }
    } 
})
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
$contextMenuStrip1.Dispose()
```

Comment: Excellent, I was sure there was a better way and this explains a lot, also means that it ignores the column headers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a cleaner way, but this works for me:

First, remove line 22 (`$listviewbox.ContextMenuStrip = $lvcontextmenu`)
and then change the Click-handler for the `$listviewbox` into:

```
$listviewbox.Add_Click({
    If($this.SelectedItems.Count){
        $this.ContextMenuStrip = $lvcontextmenu
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`n" + ($this.SelectedItems[0].Text))
    }
    Else {
        $this.ContextMenuStrip = $null
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`nNothing selected")
    }
})
```

Comment: If nothing is selected in listview, the context menu still appears - you can right click anywhere in listview and it still appears - this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Scepticalist Forgot to mention that you should remove line 22 `$listviewbox.ContextMenuStrip = $lvcontextmenu` first. Sorry..

Comment: Yeh - I did that - but it only works the first time, if you right click an item then the context menu always appears wherever you click in the listview after that. not so sure I should use a click event, using a context menu event to check might be cleaner?

Comment: @Scepticalist hmm... see what you mean. Back to the drawing board I'm afraid..

Comment: Form's `MouseDown`: `$this.ContextMenuStrip = $listviewbox.SelectedItems.Count > 0 ? $lvcontextmenu : null;`. If you actually want to use `$this`. Otherwise, just the ListView's `MouseDown` event.

Comment: No idea how that would go into the above code, can you detail?

Answer (score 0):

The following event handler works as intended - a combination of hints from both of you, thanks.

```
$listviewbox.Add_MouseUp({
    $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $null
    If($listviewbox.SelectedItems.Count){
        $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $lvcontextmenu
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`n" + ($this.SelectedItems[0].Text))
    }
    Else {
        $InfoText.AppendText("`r`nNothing selected")
        $listviewbox.contextmenustrip = $null
    }
})
```